# Prompt Javascript

Tags: javascript

O retorno do **prompt** é por padrão `String` correto? A função **`Number`** faz a conversão do retorno do prompt que é String para number. Pq então quando executo a função a seguir e coloco números entre aspas aparace a mensagem `NaN`, não deveria converter o retorno para number e executar o cálculo?

```js
var num = Number(prompt("Digite um número", ""));
alert("Seu número é a raíz quadrada de " + num * num);
```

Comment: Aqui ta funcionando. Entrada: 10; Saida: Seu número é a raíz quadrada de 100

Comment: Tenta colocar o valor entre aspas, uma String.

Comment: LeAndrade, é como você disse, o retorno de um prompt é uma string por padrão. Colocando 12 ou "12", vai ser string de qualquer forma. A diferença é que você consegue converter 12 diretamente, e "12" não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você não está a visualizar a `string` que vai ser interpretada pelo `parseInt`.

Um *input* de `12` no `prompt` vai ser como se tivesse escrito:

```
let texto = "12";
```

Mas um *input* de `"12"` é como se tivesse escrito:

```
let texto = "\"12\""; //ou texto = '"12"';
```

Repare que tem aspas dentro da própria `string` como um dos carateres dela. Por isso quando o `parseInt` tenta converter apanha uma `"` e falha pois não é numérico, resultando em `NaN` - *Not a Number*.

Teste:

```js
let texto = "12";
let texto2 = "\"12\"";

console.log(parseInt(texto));
console.log(parseInt(texto2));
```

Comment: Legal Isac, realmente não sabia como era interpretado o número com aspas.