# Maior ou menor de idade

Tags: javascript, operadores

Boa tarde pessoal.

Sou iniciante e comecei um curso de Javascript.

Estou tentando fazer esse exercicio:

3. Faça um Script para pedir o usuário o seu nome, idade, cidade de nascimento e UF. Escreva na página a seguinte frase:
   Eu [nome da pessoa], tenho x anos de idade, sou [maior ou menor de idade] e nasci na cidade de [nome da cidade] – [uf].

Fiz o seguinte porem, ele esta subsituindo a idade pelo "maior de idade" ou "menor de idade":

Exercicio 3

```
<script>

    var nome = prompt("Digite seu nome");
    var idade = prompt("Digite sua idade");
    var cidade = prompt("Digite a cidade em que nasceu");
    var uf = prompt("Digite a UF da cidade em que nasceu");
    var maiorDeIdade = "maior de idade"
    var menorDeIdade = "menor de idade"

    if (idade > 18){
        idade = maiorDeIdade

    }
    else {
        idade = menorDeIdade

    }

    document.write("Eu " + nome + ", tenho " + idade + " de idade, sou" + idade + " e nasci na cidade de " + cidade + " - " + uf );

</script>
```

Como deixar mostrando a idade em numero e se é maior ou menor ide idade?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você quer fazer `idade = idade + ' (' + maiorDeIdade + ') ';`?

Comment: No texto ele deve apresentar exemplo:

Eu Vinicius tenho 18 anos de idade, sou maior de idade e nasci na cidade de Brasilia - DF

Comment: `prompt` retorna uma *string*. por isso o JavaScript não consegue verificar se o texto "18" é maior que o número 18. Utilize o [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) ou [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para converter de *string* para *number* (*inteiro*) antes de verificar a condição de maioriade. [Resposta de outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313994/prompt-javascript)

Comment: Não deveria ser >= 18? De qualquer forma, não sobrescreva a variável idade, senão você perde o número informado pelo usuário

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o problema é que você está usando uma variável (`idade`) pra duas coisas. Crie uma variável `var maiorOuMenorDeIdade`, dentro do `if` ao invés de armazenar em `idade`, armazene nessa nova variável. E então no seu `document.write` troque o `sou + idade + ` por `sou + maiorOuMenorDeIdade + `

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/maior-ou-menor-de-idade-3d5zt

Comment: Deu certo aqui pessoal. Obrigado!

Comment: @ViniciusBarrosMarques dar certo e estar certo são coisas bem diferentes; Eu sempre posto isto para mostrar a diferença https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdAbK.jpg. Você recebeu uma resposta que faz estar certo, mais do que só ver o resultado aparecer. Alguém achou que ela está errada por ter dado um negativo, a pessoa poderia orientar o que achou de erro ali, porque eu não consegui ver.

Answer (score 5):

Como outros já comentaram, o erro principal foi reescrever a variável `idade`.

Ainda, como mencionado pelo @bfavaretto, seria `>= 18`, e tem uma comparação de string com inteiro comentada pelo @ValdeirPsr, que apesar de não impedir a execução do código, é ideal evitar.

**Para fins didáticos** seguem as correções dos comentários aplicadas em seu código original, para não misturar com outros conceitos. Obviamente que num código real não tem necessidade de se criar tantas variáveis.

Deixei `//comments` no código para mostrar o que foi alterado.

```js
var nome = prompt("Digite seu nome");
var idade = prompt("Digite sua idade");
var cidade = prompt("Digite a cidade em que nasceu");
var uf = prompt("Digite a UF da cidade em que nasceu");
var maiorDeIdade = "maior de idade";    // adicionado ; no fim das linhas
var menorDeIdade = "menor de idade";    
var maiorOuNao;                         // criamos uma variável nova

if (parseInt(idade,10) >= 18){          // adicionado parseInt e >= 
    maiorOuNao = maiorDeIdade;          // a variável nova e ; no fim da linha
}
else {
    maiorOuNao = menorDeIdade;          // a variável nova e ; no fim da linha
}

document.write("Eu " + nome + ", tenho " + idade + " anos de idade, sou " + maiorOuNao + " e nasci na cidade de " + cidade + " - " + uf );
```

Answer (score 2):

No seu código você acabou escapando da lógica, utilizando a variável `idade` para 2 ações, onde o resultado do mesmo seria

> "Eu Vinicius, tenho maior de idade de idade, sou maior de idade e nasci na cidade de São Paulo - SP"

correção do código abaixo:

```js
var nome = prompt('Digite seu nome:');
var idade = prompt('Digite sua idade:');
var cidade = prompt('Digite a cidade em que nasceu:');
var uf = prompt('Digite a UF da cidade em que nasceu:');

console.log('Eu ' +nome+ ', tenho ' +idade+ ' anos e sou ' +(idade >= 18 ? 'maior de idade' : 'menor de idade')+ ', nasci na cidade de ' +cidade+ '/'+ uf);

// ou

// document.write('Eu ' +nome+ ', tenho ' +idade+ ' anos e sou ' +(idade >= 18 ? 'maior de idade' : 'menor de idade')+ ', nasci na cidade de ' +cidade+ '/'+ uf);
```

fiz o uso da **[condição ternária](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**, para um código mais limpo! assim, excluindo as variáveis `maiorDeIdade` e `menorDeIdade` por serem "valores" fixos não teria necessidade de armazenar-os em uma variável, a não ser que fossem alteradas posteriormente. Espero que o tenha ajudado! Bons estudos.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!